# phone vs dslr vs webcam for making videos

Tags: youtube, camera, dslr, obs, iphone

I'm using OBS to record some videos for youtube with a webcam. Right now I'm using the Logitech BRIO Ultra HD. It's alright... but definitely could be better. I'm looking to upgrade to something high quality but before I shell out for a $2000 Sony A7 III which I don't feel like I can really afford, is an iPhone camera also a possibility for this usecase?

I have an iPhone 7 atm, is it already better than the Brio? If I get the iPhone 12/Galaxy S21 would it be what I need?

I'm just looking to vastly improve the quality of my videos. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe describe what you don't like about the current quality, or even provide a link to an example. Better lighting / filming environment will almost always improve visual quality more than changing camera (for what you are describing), unless your current camera is indeed exceptionally poor for some reason (I'm not familiar with it).

Comment: You’re forgetting mirrorless; cheaper than dslr because the optics are simpler, but just as good image quality. Sony just announced they’re no longer making dslrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> videos for youtube

This does not describe your projects. Youtube is a place to publish your videos, does not tell the content of them.

> but definitely could be better

What could be better? This is the point. You need to know what do you want to imporve.

Are your videos about gaming, where you are on a little corner on a green screen?

Are your videos about you talking to the camera on your room? Do you need to use the bathroom because it is the only place you have? Or you do outdoor videos. Do you really need to actually improve the image quality?

---

Let me narrow this a bit. Let me asume you are on a bedroom infront of a fixed setup, your computer and your camera. Here is a list of what would I check before getting a new camera.

1. Light.

Not only the ammount of it, but how does it look. Find a video where you like the light. Is it rim light or a big diffuse light? Is it lateral or on top of the subject?

2. Background.

Leave a good space behind you. You do not want a mug shot. Put context on it, remove yourself from the shoot and see it as the main subject, and see if you like it.

3. Sound.

Good sound is probably more important than excelent video quality.

---

If you still need better video, and you already tested your current phone. (Yes one first section on this answer is, test your phone, and find out if it is better for you) what you want to have on a new camera is

1. Looks
2. Flexibility. Duration of the shoot without heating, focus options (manual or good auto focus) conection, etc.

---

And I leave the looks to the last. A mirrorless or dslr camera have its limitations but have specific lenses that will actually make the image look good. The main things to consider are focal length and aperture.

1. A focal length of 35mm or more on a cropped sensor.
2. A wide aperture, a typical recommendation is 1.8 but needs a fixed distance or a superb auto focus system.

---

All this answer is not to tell you what you need, it is what you need to investigate to find out what you really need.